# How can I open activity when notification is touched?

Tags: java, android, class, layout, notifications

I am building a `notification` for my Music Player, so it displays what music is playing. 
But I want to add a function where, when I touch it. It opens my layout `player.xml`. Which is  deployed through the `MainActivity.class`.

I have researched on Notifications on developer.android.com and found a way to deploy and activity upon clicking the notification. But it did't work.

Here is my current code -

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                builder.setContentTitle(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle"));
                builder.setContentText("NexPlay™");
                builder.setTicker(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle"));
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play_default);
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                builder.setPriority(0);
                builder.setOngoing(true);           
                Notification notification = builder.build();
                NotificationManager notificationManger = 
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);           
                notificationManger.notify(01, notification);
```

Thanks to everyone for answering!

I added

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, NotificationToPlayer.class), 0);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

to my notifications and it worked great !

Comment: Where you have to set `Notification Content Intent` in your code?

Comment: Please follow this example http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 private void showNotification() {
        // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
        CharSequence text = getText(R.string.service_started);

        // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.android, text,
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, ServiceLauncher.class), 0);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.service_label),
                       text, contentIntent);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        // Send the notification.
        // We use a layout id because it is a unique number.  We use it later to cancel.
        nm.notify(R.string.service_started, notification);
    }
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you, yours was most helpful and simple, I just added -           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, NotificationToPlayer.class), 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent); and t worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll also want to add an intent. Something like:

```
Intent actIntent = new Intent(this, do MyActivity.class);
```

Then in your builder:

```
.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(MyActivity, 131314, actIntent,
                  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add intent on ur code:-

```
int icon = R.drawable.app_launcher;
                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message.split(":::")[1], when);

                String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
                Intent notificationIntent = null;
                    notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MessageDetail.class);

                PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message.split(":::")[1], intent);
                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

                // Play default notification sound
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```